# Importing Silver into the US - what duty will I pay?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

Do I need to declare the silver tableware I am carrying into the U.S.? I will be getting an export certificate from India. The rules are not very clear on what to do at the U.S. end. What is the quantity I can bring into the U.S., and will I pay any duty?

Comment: Is this tableware your personal property and going to be for your personal use?

Answer (score 5):

According to [Duty Calculator](http://www.dutycalculator.com/popular-import-items/import-duty-and-taxes-for-silver-jewellery/) :

> " The global average import duty rate for Silver jewellery is 6.9%,
>   with a minimum of 0% and a maximum of 35%. "

You can use this to calculate your import. I can't do it for you because it very much depends on what type of tableware.

So on the pop-up, choose "Home and Garden", then "Kitchenware and  Tableware" and then the type of Tableware yours fits into.

I chose sterling silver, for example, and for the US it states that the duty rate is 3.3%, and additional taxes will depend on which state you're entering into when you arrive.

Declaring it will depend on the value, but if unsure, ALWAYS declare it, and they'll help you value it. If you're caught not declaring something that you're supposed to, it won't end well.